# Passing array of Variables to another sub to fill them returns variables empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying a piece of code to fill some variables passing them inside an array to another sub. I'm doing it this way because now I need to fill 4 variables, but in the future it may change so I don't want to write as much parameters on the sub procedure.

The important code is here:

```
Private Sub CargaDatosFicheros(arr As Variant)
    'Proceso que carga los datos de cada fichero dependiendo de los campos que tenga cada uno.
    Dim Encabezados As Dictionary: Set Encabezados = CargaEncabezados(arr, 1)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Centro As String, Modo As String, Agente As String
    Dim Fecha As Date
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim arrVariables() As Variant
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        arrVariables = Array(Centro, "Centro", Modo, "Modo", Agente, "Agente", Fecha, "Fecha")
        If arr(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For
        CargaCamposFijos Encabezados, arr, i, arrVariables
        For Each Key In Equivalencias.Keys
            If Encabezados.Exists(Key) Then
                If CompruebaFiltro(Encabezados, arr, i, Key) Then
                    Modos(Modo).Centros(Centro).Fechas(Fecha).KPIs(Equivalencias(Key)).Valor = arr(i, Encabezados(Key))
                    If Not FechasFiltro.Exists(Fecha) Then FechasFiltro.Add Fecha, 1
                End If
            End If
        Next Key
    Next i

End Sub
Private Sub CargaCamposFijos(Encabezados As Dictionary, arr As Variant, i As Long, ByRef arrVariables As Variant)
    'Proceso que busca del diccionario campos fijos situado en la hoja EquivalenciasCampos
    'Cuáles de los encabezados del archivo contienen el dato que quiere para rellenar los campos de Modo, Centro, Agente y Fecha
    'Dichos campos se pueden cambiar al llamar esta función.
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    For j = LBound(arrVariables) To UBound(arrVariables) Step 2
        For Each Key In CamposFijos.Keys
            If Encabezados.Exists(Key) And CamposFijos(Key) = arrVariables(j + 1) Then
                arrVariables(j) = IIf(arrVariables(j + 1) = "Fecha", arr(i, Encabezados(Key)), Filtros(arr(i, Encabezados(Key))).Valor)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Key
    Next j

End Sub
```

the line `arrVariables = Array(Centro, "Centro", Modo, "Modo", Agente, "Agente", Fecha, "Fecha")` is the one holding the variables.

The line `CargaCamposFijos Encabezados, arr, i, arrVariables` calls the procedure which will call them.

The subprocedure returns all the variables as expected:

[image: Variables_Filled]

But once the macro returns to the previous procedure the "independent" variables (`Modo, Centro, Agente, Fecha`) are still empty:

[image: Variables_Empty]

I'm sure there is something missing here or I don't get how this works. Is it possible that if I declare some variables and then add them to an array and fill this array in another procedure, the variables will get the value aswell?

Comment: What is `Equivalencias`? You're trying to loop through it but there's nothing in it. Or is there?

Comment: Sorry @VBasic2008, it is, just not in this scope. The problem is that I don't know if my goal can be achieved. Declaring some variables such as `Modo As String, Centro As String, Agente As String, Fecha As Date`. Then passing them to an array and finally passing this array to the other procedure to fill these variables. It works fine, the array is filled, but when it returns, the independent variables are still empty.

Comment: Create a class and put all your variables in it as properties. Then just pass the class to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Call for that line of code, or remove the parens.

```
Call CargaCamposFijos(Encabezados, arr, i, arrVariables)
```

Proof that it makes a difference:

```
Private Sub ArrayByRefTest()
    
    Dim arrVariables As Variant
                    
    ' Fail
    arrVariables = Array(Centro, "Centro", Modo, "Modo", Agente, "Agente", Fecha, "Fecha")
    CargaCamposFijos (arrVariables)
    For j = LBound(arrVariables) To UBound(arrVariables)
        Debug.Print (arrVariables(j))
    Next j

    ' Success
    arrVariables = Array(Centro, "Centro", Modo, "Modo", Agente, "Agente", Fecha, "Fecha")
    Call CargaCamposFijos(arrVariables)
    For j = LBound(arrVariables) To UBound(arrVariables)
        Debug.Print (arrVariables(j))
    Next j

End Sub

Private Sub CargaCamposFijos(ByRef arrVariables As Variant)
    
    For j = LBound(arrVariables) To UBound(arrVariables)
        arrVariables(j) = "test" & j
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: How would this help me? Besides the `Call` instance is no longer needed.

Comment: There, I posted a simple test to prove it.

Comment: Well, what did you find @Damian

Comment: You may want to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code. Improper use of parentheses in `CargaCamposFijos (arrVariables)` is the problem, and the use of `Call` is not required. By the same reasoning, `Debug.Print (arrVariables(j))` is problematic, as would be `MsgBox ("foo")` for example.

Comment: @BigBen It's fine, we're not flying rockets here. Call may not be required but VBA is definitely behaving differently between using Call and not.

Comment: As my comment mentioned, the *parentheses* are the problem. Drop them and `CargaCamposFijos arrVariables` will succeed.... though [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802823/passing-array-of-variables-to-another-sub-to-fill-them-returns-variables-empty/66804838?noredirect=1#comment118089621_66802823) is probably the right answer. But the first sentence "You must use Call" is most certainly not right.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Yeah. Well, it is right for that line of code. ;-) heh heh.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. But this doesn't help. The array of variables keeps their value, but the declared values such as `Modo` will stay empty no matter what just like on my second screenshot. Where my variables inside `arrVariables` are filled, but not the ones above @NickAbbot